# Flash/Flex-like data binding in CreateJS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, data-binding, createjs

Maybe somebody knows about the best way to implement data binding in CreateJS? E.g. when changes of properties in ClassA call some listener-functions in ClassB ?

In Flash(Flex) it's possible to use some meta-tags to tell compiler which properties should be used as bindable. After that, during compilation compiler makes some changes in the code (e.g. wraps the required properties into get/set methods, and in the set methods there are dispatching events functionality).

Do we have something similar in CreateJS?

How it works in AS3 (a very simple example):

```
public class ClassA
{
    [Bindable]
    public var bindableProperty:String;
}

public class ClassB
{
    protected var classA:ClassA;

    public function GameModel()
    {
        this.classA = new ClassA();
        BindingUtils.bindSetter(this.bindingCallback, this.classA, "bindableProperty");
    }

    public function bindingCallback()
    {
        // Do something after binding callback
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing like that in Javascript, javascript is not compiled so no metadata is possible, javascript is not OOP so no getter/setter are possible. Make your own system.

Comment: @BotMaster Actually, there are getter/setters supported in most browsers today (IE8+), and that's the closest workaround to implementing data-binding.

Comment: it's merely a get/set workaround javascript style. Let's keep OOP definitions where they belong: in OOP languages.

Comment: @BotMaster [JavaScript has getter/setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and [is an OOP language according to wikipedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). I agree that compared to AS3 it's not nearly "as OOP", but that doesn't mean it doesn't offer something helpful and relevant to the OP.

Comment: wikipedia really? If that is your source of information then I guess anything's possible. If instead you compare javascript with the basic 4 fundamental principles of OOP foundation ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no near equivalent to the `[Bindable]` Flex meta-tag in JavaScript or CreateJS.

In the future, [`Object.observe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) could be a close equivalent to Flex's `bindSetter`.

For now you can use getter/setter properties to invoke callbacks when properties are changed. [Here's a simple example:](http://jsfiddle.net/abeall/45aojcmk/1/)

```
function bindSetter(host, property, callback) {
    if(!host[property + "_bindings"]){
        host[property + "_bindings"] = [];
        host["_" + property] = host[property];
        Object.defineProperty(host, property, {
            get: function() { 
                return host["_" + property]; 
            }, 
            set: function(newValue) {
                host["_" + property] = newValue;
                host[property + "_bindings"].forEach(function(callback){
                    callback(newValue);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    host[property + "_bindings"].push(callback);
}
```

Now you can use `bindSetter` in a similar way to Flex:

```
var user = { name: "Aaron" }

bindSetter(user, "name", function(newValue){
    log("Callback: " + newValue);
});

bindSetter(user, "name", function(newValue){
    log("Another callback: " + newValue);
});

log("Initial value: " + user.name);

user.name = "Joe";
```

Should output:

> - Initial value: Aaron
> - Callback: Joe
> - Another callback: Joe

Binding to DOM element values is another problem, though, as they do not behave the same as regular JavaScript objects. Of course, there are many JS frameworks out there to accomplish data-binding with DOM elements, like Angular, Backbone, Knockout, etc. Mileage will vary when trying to mix other frameworks with CreateJS, though.

**Update:** 
[An equivalent `unbindSetter`](http://jsfiddle.net/abeall/45aojcmk/2/) could be done as follows:

```
function unbindSetter(host, property, callback){
    var bindings = host[property + "_bindings"];
    if(bindings){
        var index = bindings.indexOf(callback);
        if(index > -1){
            bindings.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can remove a callback that was previously added:

```
var user = { name: "Aaron" }

bindSetter(user, "name", myCallback);
function myCallback(newValue){
    alert("Callback: " + newValue);
}

user.name = "Joe"; // alerts "Callback: Joe"

unbindSetter(user, "name", myCallback);

user.name = "Bob"; // no alert
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for the great explanation!

Comment: Sorry, if I'm wrong, but am I right that this solution has potential problems with Garbage Collection? I mean, there is no way to remove binding?

Comment: You could add a method to remove the bindings. I can post an example. But your concern in general is valid, this is kind of a low level hack you should use carefully.

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks again for the solution. I think it would be a problem for me to write "remove" method by myself.